# Finger Print Sensor Not Detecting

Tags: arduino, sensors, fingerprint

I am using an R307 Finger Print Sensor.
I have done all the wiring connections as described in tutorial.

- Red wire:vcc
- Black wire:GND
- Green wire: Arduino Uno pin 2
- White wire: Arduino Uno pin 3

But i am getting error: Did not find fingerprint sensor.
Function  `finger.verifypassword()` always fails.
How to get rid of this error ?
I am using  `#include adafruit Fingerprint.h` library by adafruit and `#include softwareSerial.h` Standard Libraries.

Comment: Without any code or example, no one can guess what is happening.

Comment: (https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-optical-fingerprint-sensor.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to Arduino pins 0 and 1 for serial comms. Pin 2 & 3 are not going to get you anywhere. RX is the white wire and goes to pin 0, TX is the green wire and goes to pin 1.

**Edit:**
If you need to use soft serial first try with normal serial on pins 0,1 and verifying everything is functional before moving to soft serial.

Comment: He is probably using software serial on pins 2 & 3.

Comment: @gre_gor I did not even think of the option. I think that is what he is trying...